# Am I misunderstood? The answer that appears to be distorted about DFS

Tags: c++

The answer are wrong Am I misunderstood? in DFS
Could someone please advice where the mistake has been done at my end?
I have checked that there is no bug in the program but the answer is wrong.
this for my test case

```
6
10
4 3
3 1
3 4
5 2
5 6
6 5
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 5
1
```

this is my input.

result is `1 2 5 6 3 4`.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
const int N = 10000;
vector<bool> vis(N, -1);
vector<int> adj[N]; /// keep adj list
bool visited[N];
int dis[N] = {0};

void DFS(int start){
    cout << start << " ";
    vis[start] = true;
    for(int i=0;i<adj[start].size() ; i++){
        if(vis[i] == -1){
            DFS(i);
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    int edge, node;
    cin >> node;
    cin >> edge;
    for (int i = 0; i < edge; i++){
        int first,second;
        cin >> first;
        cin >> second;
        adj[first].push_back(second);
        adj[second].push_back(first);
    }
    int start_node;
    cin >> start_node;

    DFS(start_node);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take some time to pick proper tags. This is no C code. I also don't see where this is related to distributed file system. These tags are incorrect and should not be added.

Comment: What answers are wrong? What input do you provide, what output do you get and what output do you expect?

Comment: Please add this to the question. Comments might be discarded.

Comment: `vis` is a vector of `bool`. Why are you trying to initialize it with -1 or comparing elements with -1? The elements are either `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `if(vis[i] == -1)` to work you need to initialize all the values in your vector to -1 before starting the algorithm.

Also, I would advise you to use `vector<bool>` instead.

Comment: i try it and result is 4 only

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is not good. it should go

```cpp
for (const auto elem : adj[start])
    {
        if(!vis[elem])
        {
            DFS(elem);
        }
    }
```

That is, you need to iterate over adj ELEMENTS, not over number of elements.

Other way to iterate over elements would be to change your if statement to be

```
if(!vis[adj[start][i]])
```

but that leaves you with other possible errors, so stick to the one above.

Also, you have many other errors, such as node variable not being used and you have duplicate edges, but all of those are fixable with some practice.

Happy learning!